# template constructor for expression node returns wrong value

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, copy

I have a template class that just seems to fail this on one test.

- There is a template structure "term" representing the node values of an expression graph.
- There is a template structure "expression" representing the graph.
- There is a test procedure "void Test()"

I have beat my head for a few hours now. I would really like some assistance.

```
void Test()
{
    cout << "****  Integer Tests" << endl;
    // Default Constructor
    integer a;
    cout << "integer a = "<< a.Value << endl;
    // Copy Constructor
    integer b(a);
    cout << "integer b(a) = "<< b.Value << endl;
    integer c = b;
    cout << "integer c = b = "<< c.Value << endl;
    // Type Constructor
    integer d(5);
    cout << "integer d(5) = "<< d.Value << endl;
    integer e = 5;
    cout << "integer e = 5 = "<< e.Value << endl;
    // Type Conversions
    int n = e.Value;
    cout << "n = e = "<< n << endl;/
    n = (int)d.Value + (int)e.Value;
    cout << "n = d + e = "<< n << endl;// allowed because a convers to int

    cout << "****  Expression Tests" << endl;
    expression<int> e1;
    expression<int> e2(e1);

    expression<int> e3(d);// This line using the copy constructor works
    expression<int> e4 = d + e;// this line, using the copy constructor AFTER the operator+ call results in BUM values.

}
```

The test function "void Test()" fails to give the correct value for the statement :

expression e4 = d + e;

stepping through the call stack...at T+1

1.) calls term::expression& operator+(term& ref)

2.) on return, the left and right values of the expression node are CORRECT!!!

3.) now, the assignment that fails...  it calls copy constructor expression(expression& ref)

4.)  WTF??? inside this i get bum left and right values.

why, when the copy constructor test succeeds at the line above?

here are the test case templates

```
template<typename T> struct expression; // Forward Declare expressions, so i can use it in operator+

template<typename T>
struct term
{
    T Value;
    term() : Value(0) 
    { 
        cout << "****  term()" << endl;
    } // Default Constructor
    term(term& ref) : Value(ref.Value) 
    { 
        cout << "****  term(term& ref)" << endl;
    } // Copy Constructor
    // Type Conversion
    term(T value) : Value(value) 
    { 
        cout << "****  term(T value)" << endl;
    } // Type Constructor
    //operator T() const { return Value; } // Type Converter
    **expression<T>& operator+(term& ref) 
    {
        return expression<T>(*this, ref);
    };**
};

template<typename T>
struct expression
{
    term<T> Left;
    term<T> Right;
    expression() 
        : Left()
        , Right() 
    { 
        cout << "****  expression()" << endl;
        cout << "left" << Left.Value << endl;
        cout << "right" << Right.Value << endl;
    }
    expression(expression& ref) 
        : Left(ref.Left)
        , Right(ref.Right) 
    { 
        cout << "****  expression(expression& ref)" << endl;
        cout << "left" << Left.Value << endl;
        cout << "right" << Right.Value << endl;
    }
    expression(term<T>& left) 
        : Left(left)
        , Right() 
    { 
        cout << "****  expression(term<T>& left)" << endl;
        cout << "left" << Left.Value << endl;
        cout << "right" << Right.Value << endl;
    }
    expression(term<T>& left, term<T>& right) 
        : Left(left)
        , Right(right) 
    { 
        cout << "****  expression(term<T>& left, term<T>& right)" << endl;
        cout << "left" << Left.Value << endl;
        cout << "right" << Right.Value << endl;
    }
};
struct integer : public term<int> 
{ 

    integer() : term() { }// allows default constructor (not inheritablle)
    // tactic to get base class constructors(1 parameter) to compile...
    template<class T> integer(T t) : term(t) { }
    //template<class T> integer(T& t) : term(t) { }
};
void Test()
{
    cout << "****  Integer Tests" << endl;
    // Default Constructor
    integer a;
    cout << "integer a = "<< a.Value << endl;// allowed because integer converts to int
    // Copy Constructor
    integer b(a);
    cout << "integer b(a) = "<< b.Value << endl;
    integer c = b;
    cout << "integer c = b = "<< c.Value << endl;
    // Type Constructor
    integer d(5);
    cout << "integer d(5) = "<< d.Value << endl;
    integer e = 5;
    cout << "integer e = 5 = "<< e.Value << endl;
    // Type Conversions
    int n = e.Value;
    cout << "n = e = "<< n << endl;// allowed because a convers to int
    // Arithmetic using base type operators... whatever they allow, is allowed.
    n = (int)d.Value + (int)e.Value;
    cout << "n = d + e = "<< n << endl;// allowed because a convers to int

    cout << "****  Expression Tests" << endl;
    expression<int> e1;
    expression<int> e2(e1);

    expression<int> e3(d);// This line using the copy constructor works
    expression<int> e4 = d + e;// this line, using the copy constructor AFTER the operator+ call results in BUM values.

}
```

Output of the above code looks like:

```
****  Integer Tests
****  term()
integer a = 0
****  term(term& ref)
integer b(a) = 0
****  term(term& ref)
integer c = b = 0
****  term(T value)
integer d(5) = 5
****  term(T value)
integer e = 5 = 5
n = e = 5
n = d + e = 10
****  Expression Tests
****  term()
****  term()
****  expression()
left0
right0
****  term(term& ref)
****  term(term& ref)
****  expression(expression& ref)
left0
right0
****  term(term& ref)
****  term()
****  expression(term<T>& left)
left5
right0
****  term(term& ref)
****  term(term& ref)
****  expression(term<T>& left, term<T>& right)
left5
right5
****  term(term& ref)
****  term(term& ref)
****  expression(expression& ref)
left4061292
right4061296
```

**Edit:**  as pointed out (very quickly, I might add) the operator+ was returning the reference to a temp on the stack, and not the value as I assumed.

The function was fixed such that the ampersand after expression was removed:

```
expression<T> operator+(term& ref) 
    {
        return expression<T>(*this, ref);
    };
```

This was an ID10T error.  the ampersand was right there in front of me.

Again, Thanks for helping me resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
expression<T>& operator+(term& ref)
```

`operator+` should return a new object. You're returning a reference to a temporary. That shouldn't even compile, but I'm guessing you're using MSVC which has an extension to allow this for reasons that I don't understand.

There's other problems in your code that should prevent it from compiling to, but that's likely the one that's causing your error. As a first approximation, every use of reference in your code is incorrect - they should all either be references to `const`  or values.

Comment: Umm, the code DOES in fact compile.  The code even works on the line RIGHT ABOVE the error line.  the intent, is that the operator + returns a expression structure on the stack as a return value (it's just 64 bits).  the typical operator+ returns a reference to itself... i cannot do that.  this code even works in the line above it.   sorry, not the right answer.

Comment: please note:  it does one operator + call, returns correctly to the copy constructor... where teh value is correct and that it is the second copy of the assignment statement... where the ref copy created on the stack.. is returned.   what you are saying , is i'm seeing stack overwritting my copy before I can copy it?  frap... you may be right.

Comment: @GunterDon typical `operator+=` returns reference to itself. `operator+` returns by value.  Use `/Za` compiler switch in MSVC to make it give errors for these invalid bindings.

Comment: thanks, you guys are awsome.  son of a gun.  passed reference when should be value.